# Objective C on Windows - Error - CreateProcess: No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, g++, mingw, gnustep

I've just installed GNUStep, MSYS, Code and Devel to allow me develop applications in Objective C on Windows. I followed all the instructions and realized that I got a problem.
When I do:
`C:\Users\Marcelo> g++ o.m` in console, I get the following:

`=>g++: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`

I saw 4 similar questions in StackOverflow, but none of them had any relationship to Objective C and none of the answers led me to solve it. I've done all that was asked:

- Restart computer
- Check environment path
- Access `C:\GNUStep\bin\g++` to perform the action

#### My variable path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo IDE 8\;
C:\app\marcelo\product\11.2.0\client_1;
C:\app\marcelo\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\bin;
C:\Perl64\site\bin;
C:\Perl64\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;
C:\LLVM\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.3.2\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
C:\Users\marcelo\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;
C:\Ruby193\bin;
C:\Users\marcelo\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\clisp-2.49;
C:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools;
C:\GNUstep\bin;
C:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools;
C:\GNUstep\bin;
C:\GNUstep\GNUstep\System\Tools
```

Can someone give me a hand?

- Isn't the location of the file. If I specify a non-existant file, it throws me **another** error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only see Haskell's MinGW in your path. Try

1. Compiling from inside GNUStep shell - the necessary paths may already be configured.
2. Add your MinGW\bin directory to windows path
3. Temporarily removing Haskell mingw distro from path.

Failing that, post results of using g++ -v